# Error installing Plugin Registration in XrmToolbox

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, workflow, microsoft-dynamics, xrmtoolbox

I downloaded XrmToolbox to my computer, connected to Dynamics environment and tried to install Plugin Registration tool. Unfortunately, I encountered this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxfq2.png)
How can this be solved? Thanks in advance!

I reinstalled the application several times, but in vain...

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone. I see that the issue was reported already - https://github.com/Innofactor/PluginRegistration/issues/132
I would recommend downloading Plugin Registration Tool from Microsoft to work with plugins instead - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.PluginRegistrationTool/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple work arounds available. Any one of the following will work.

1. Install and use XTB 1.2022.10.58
2. Replace the Microsfot.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces in the XTB folder with the 6.0 version
3. Place the Microsfot.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces 6.0 version dll in a sub folder of the XTB's plugin directory
4. Add an assembly binding redirect to the XTB.exe.config to redirect 6.0 to 7.0

Taken from https://github.com/MscrmTools/XrmToolBox/issues/1312

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in the end: install it via vs -> nuget package manager.
(You can use the following screenshots: [Navigation in Vs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBwze.png)
[Navigation in Vs 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBwze.png))
You can install for a specific project. Then in the file explorer open the tools folder, find the folder: Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.PluginRegistrationTool. run the execution file and pin it to the taskbar so you can use it for any plugin and application you want (It doesn't really matter through which project you installed it...)

Answer (score 0):

This happens in XrmToolBox. I recommend running [`pac tool prt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/developer/cli/reference/tool#pac-tool-prt) as another option.